# Add a video into splash screen or in the first view of the app (IOS xcode 4.0)

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, xcode4, splash-screen

I'm a beginner in IOS but I need to show a video when the app is launching.
Please Can you help me?

If is impossible to implement a video on a splash view, there are any idea to create that?

Thanks.

If I have an orthographic mistake, sorry I come from Spain. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "splash" screen can only be an image to be used as a placeholder until your app is able to start up. Even if you found a way to get a video to play, which I don't think is possible, it is against Apple's HIG for how the startup screen is supposed to be used.

It would be possible to load your video in its own view immediately after the splash screen. You would need to check for a first time run to determine whether to show it, unless you plan to show it each and every time. Hope this helps.

[Apple Human Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1)